# Until the browser is closed, session maintain without cookie in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using codeigniter php framework now in developing backend web application.
But session is often expired.
My config.php(application/config/ folder) is ;

```
  $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
    $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
    $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

In codeigniter guide, $config['sess_expiration'] = 0 -> "maintains session  until the browser is closed .".

By the way, in my web application, when the user does nothing for a little time (about 30 mins), session is expired, so users must login again.

What shall I set in config.php?

Comment: You may have to make an adjustment to the php.ini file, as the default is  24 minutes (1440 seconds).  If you are going through a hosting company, they might have a different setting.

Comment: Also you have not set your save path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is related to the php.ini file.

In php.ini file, I could find this line.

```
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440
```

This value is second unit, and 24 minutes later, session is auto closed.

So I solved this problem by setting this value a large number.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try it working for me..

Just add `$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;`.

```
    $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
    $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
    $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
    $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
```